# String concatenation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, concatenation

I am using MySQL and MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE. When I try to concatenate 2 columns, `last_name` and `first_name`, it doesn't work :

```
select first_name + last_name as "Name" from test.student
```

Answer (score 423):

MySQL is different from most DBMSs' use of `+` or `||` for concatenation. It uses the [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS Name FROM test.student
```

There's also the [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) (Concatenate With Separator) function, which is a special form of `CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) from test.student
```

That said, if you want to treat `||` as a string concatenation operator (same as `CONCAT()`) rather than as a synonym for `OR` in MySQL, you can set the [`PIPES_AS_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) SQL mode.

Comment: Better answer, explains that MySQL doesn't use concatenation operators.

Comment: For those using `Doctrine`, I had to use single quotes for the space in `CONCAT`, and double quotes around the entire query.

Comment: To set `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`: `SET @@SQL_MODE = CONCAT(@@SQL_MODE, ',PIPES_AS_CONCAT');`. To unset: `SET @@SQL_MODE = REPLACE(@@SQL_MODE, 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT', '');`. More examples at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-mode/#examples

Answer (score 35):

Try:

```
select concat(first_name,last_name) as "Name" from test.student
```

or, better:

```
select concat(first_name," ",last_name) as "Name" from test.student
```

Answer (score 13):

Use [concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function instead of `+` like this:

```
select concat(firstname, lastname) as "Name" from test.student
```

Answer (score 6):

Apart from `concat` you can also use `concat_ws` (concatenate with separator):

`SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) from test.student`

This function has the added benefit of skipping `null` values.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

Answer (score 3):

That's not the way to concat in MYSQL. Use the CONCAT function Have a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat