# Concatenation of columns mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of addresses in a database containing USA zip codes

the columns in table are called zip5 and zip4

I want to combine these zip codes with - in between that

I am currently using mysql the query i am using is

select zip5,zip4, concat(zip5,'-',zip4) zip from address limit 500;

now there are certain occasions where zip4 column is null but there is data in zip5 column

in this situation new concatenated column call zip becomes null.

I dont want this to happen. if zip4 does not have data at least it should show data from zip5 with no - in between that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975958/mysql-concatenation)

Comment: @ChrisB That question relates to the incorrect use of + for concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE`

```
select zip5, 
       zip4,
       concat(zip5,'-',coalesce(zip4,'')) zip 
from address
```

or better [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

```
select zip5, 
       zip4,
       CONCAT_WS('-', zip5, zip4) zip 
from address
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN zip4 IS NULL THEN zip5
        ELSE concat(zip5,'-',zip4) 
    END zip 
from address limit 500;
```