# mysql - LEFT JOIN two tables with columns that almost match

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in which I need to join. Problem is the only fields I can use in each table are not totally identical, but it is all I can use.

```
Voting.movie_id = a123456789
Movies.movie_id = 123456789
```

As you can see one has the letter 'a' in the front. The rest totally matches and always will. Its just that 'a' in front that makes it different.

I was hoping there was a way to do this with a join so I tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM voting 
RIGHT JOIN movies ON voting.movie_id = 'a'+movies.movie_id 
ORDER BY voting.ID DESC 
LIMIT 40

SELECT * 
FROM voting 
RIGHT JOIN movies ON voting.movie_id = '%'+movies.movie_id 
ORDER BY voting.ID DESC 
LIMIT 40
```

This did not work, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why `%`? Wildcards only work with `LIKE`, not `=`;

Comment: Hey you have to try something once you know :)

Comment: I do not think this question should be marked as much as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975958/mysql-concatenation just because I had no idea that `Concatenation` meant what it did. For those of us who do not know how to word this particular syntax this might help others get the answer.

Comment: You knew that you wanted to concatenate `a` and the movie ID, you just didn't know the correct syntax for that. The answer in that question solves it, doesn't it?

Comment: The questions may not be identical, but that's just because you didn't know how to express the question correctly. The answer is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you concatenate strings using the `CONCAT()` function, not `+`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM voting 
RIGHT JOIN movies ON voting.movie_id = CONCAT('a', movies.movie_id)
ORDER BY voting.ID DESC 
LIMIT 40
```