# Insert into table concatenation of variables and constant tokens

Tags: mysql, concatenation, sql-insert, user-variables

I have a table with the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `myfield` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I've defined a couple of variables as follows

```
SET @NAME := 'Somename';
SET @AGE := '31';
```

I need to insert into the table an entry composed of the concatenation of these user-defined variables and constant tokens. I've tried the following query

```
INSERT INTO `foo` (`myfield`) VALUES
('Name: ' + @NAME + ' Age: ' + @AGE);
```

The statement execution succeds, but after insertion `myfield` equals to:

```
31
```

It's just like the first part of the inserted value is ignored. What am I missing?

Comment: + is not a mysql string concatenation function use concat verb.

Comment: That worked! Thank you @P.Salmon

Comment: This is how **NOT** to store data in a database... please don't do it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String concatenation in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975958/string-concatenation-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

First. Go read about database normalization. The way you hope to store name and age is a terrible misuse of SQL. If you pass your application, written this way, on to other programmers they will curse your name to the thousandth generation. Seriously.

Second. The `+` operator in MySQL does addition. If you do `'any string' + 42`, two things happen:

1. MySQL sees that it's adding numbers and coerces `'any string'` to a number: then number zero.
2. it adds zero to 42.

You want to use `CONCAT('Name: ', @NAME, ' Age: ', @AGE)`

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit you answer, and add another one that explain the full "good way".

Answer (score 1):

This how you should deal with this kind of data :

1. you don't want you age to be the same next year, so you store the date of birth
2. when you insert, you store one information per field
3. on the output `SELECT` you `CONCAT` what you want .

So :

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
    `NAME` text NOT NULL,
    `BIRTH` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `foo` (`NAME`, `BIRTH`)
VALUES (@NAME, @BIRTH);


SELECT CONCAT(
    'Name: ',
    `foo`.`NAME`,
    ' Age: ',
     TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,`foo`.`BIRTH`,CURDATE())
     )
FROM `foo`
```

Comment: Hi Blag, thanks for the response. Age was just an example. The real case is similar to what you described in this answer, with just only constant (invariable) values, like name or birth. The goal was just to parametrize the query. Thanks for the explanation.