# What is the function to combine columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

Write a select statement that returns one column from the customers table named full_name that joins the last-name and first_name columns

Select last_name, first_name
From customers
Join

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String concatenation in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5975958/328193)

Answer (score 0):

To combine column in mysql use CONCAT function

```
SELECT CONCAT (column1, " ", column2) FROM TABLE
```

you can concat column or string like in example