# Is there a way to use SQL WHERE with multiple columns PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a database with firstname and lastname columns. Is there a way to query these togheter, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE firstname + ' ' + lastname = :fullName
```

Currently this query gives me multiple results even when the firstname and lastname do not match at all with the fullName variable.

Comment: You can use `CONCAT()` to .. concatenate values

Comment: Also, just to be certain of the operator precedence, you can put parens around the `firstname + ' ' + lastname`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? AFAIK, `+` for concatenation is SQL Server only. ANSI SQL has `||` concatenation operand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String concatenation in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975958/string-concatenation-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) = :fullName

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).