# What is the correct SQL query statement for "SELECT LIKE" using tableadapter query configuration wizard for visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, search

I want to know what is the correct SQL query statement for "SELECT LIKE" in the TableAdapter query configuration wizard with a parameter in visual studio and want to add a query for search purposes because it's really hard to find the answer I need on the internet so please can someone help me

THIS IS WHAT I WROTE:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE '%'+@name+'%'
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5975980/23633), you can't use `+` to concatenate strings in MySQL; instead, use the [`CONCAT` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', @name, '%')
```

Comment: is it also working in visual studio?

Comment: and the configuration says "Error in WHERE clause near ','. Unable to parse query text.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Visual Studio 2013 or the TableAdapter query configuration wizard. Sounds like a bug in that feature if it can't parse completely valid SQL.